# Bootstrap: button on a simple form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap, if I have a form like this:

```
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend>Legend</legend>
<label>Label name</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Type something…">
<button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

The button stay beside input. But I need it stay on bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add:

```
.block {
    display:block
}
```

To the end of bootstrap.css, then add the class of "block" to your submit button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn block">Submit</button>
```